# Probability of Permutation of Digits

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

What is the probability that a permutation of the ten digits is in numeric order $(0-9)$?

The caveat is that at least one of the digits is in the proper place for the permutation, but we do not know which digit.

For the permutation, would it be using the formula $nPr = n! / (n - r)!$ with $n = 10, r = 10?$ Or would it be $9$, keeping one digit constant?

Comment: Think a little about the problem before asking youself "which formula to use". What would be you answer if you don't know that fact (at least one digit in the proper place) ? Could you check that result for small numbers (say, 2 or 3 instead of 10)?

Comment: Would it be 10^10? For 2 numbers, it would be 2^2.

Comment: No, take the digits $\{0, 1, 2, 4\}$.  Count the distinct ways to rearrange them such that at least one of the digits is in the 'correct' position.

Comment: so then, for the original problem... 10C1 = 10 ways to select one number in the right position, followed by 9! ways to select the remaining 9? 
10 x 9!

Comment: Yes, now to avoid over-counting use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion. @user289332

Comment: The permutations with no digits in the proper position are called derangements. You can search this site or Wikipedia for how to compute the number, then subtract them from all permutations

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we take the digits $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ and count distinct arrangements that have at least one of the digits in the correct place.

There are $3!$ ways a particular digit can be in the correct place, and there are $4$ digits, but this is over counting.   Applying Inclusion and Exclusion:   There are $2!$ ways to arrange so two particular digits are in correct place, and there are $6$ ways to select two such digits.   There are $1!$ ways to arrange so that three particular digits are in place and four ways to select them.   There is $0!$ way to arrange so that four particular digits are in place and one way to select it.

$$4! - \frac{4!}{2!2!}\cdot 2!+ \frac{4!}{3!1!}1! - \frac{4!}{4!0!}0! = 4!\left(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}\right) = 15$$

$$\require{cancel}\begin{array}{l}
 0123 & 0132 & 0213 & 0231 & 0312 & 0321 \\
 1023 & \xcancel{1032} & 1203 & \xcancel{1230} & \xcancel{1302} & 1320 \\
 2013 & \xcancel{2031} & 2103 & 2130 & \xcancel{2301} & \xcancel{2310} \\
 \xcancel{3012} & 3021 & 3102 & 3120 & \xcancel{3201} & \xcancel{3210} \end{array}$$

Extend this to the case of the original $10$ digit list.